# Dynamically load an entire angular app

Tags: html, angularjs, dom, dynamic, controller

So I have a curious situation and I don't think it's going to work, but I figured I'd ask in case it is and someone knows how to. I am using a 3rd party website to create marketing funnels. You can add your own custom html and javascript, but it parses out the html in a rather unfavorable manor. Basically you specify an element on the page and it appends it as a data attribute and dynamically loads it into the DOM. Since this is happening this way, my app isn't being initialized because it's not in the DOM on page load. Is there a way to make this work? I'll explain a little deeper my configuration.

I add custom html such as:

```
<div data-ng-app="AppName"><div data-ng-controller="ControllerName"><div>perform controller logic here</div></div>
```

As you can see, this needs to be in the DOM for the app to initialize and, well work. Is there a way to initialize the app after the page has loaded dynamically? I can add my own JS files in the custom html field, but thats about as far as I can go for customization. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should execute angular's bootstrap function manually in your script after the required dom loaded.

```
var app = angular.module('appName', []);
app.controller([...]);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('divId'), ['appName']);
```

For more information, you can see this doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I need. I'll give it a go. Thanks for the advice!